# How to use a coroutine inside forEach loop in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutinescope

I want have an array of objects which I want to loop over and send every object using a post request and CoroutineScope to server.

Comment: Could you please add some example code - otherwiese its too vague.

Comment: From Review: Edit your question and add your code please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pattern:

1. Map your list/array to async jobs
2. Map list of async jobs to their result

In code, it'd look like this

```
myData.map { data ->
    async {
        callToServer(data)
    }
}.map {
    it.await()
}
```

This would run each callToServer in separate job concurrently.

Comment: I actually ended up using a recursive function. Calling function again on success and checking with a condition to break it. Is this right way ?